# google cloud function - mysql and sqlalchemy good practice in create_engine configuration

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions, connection-pooling

Are there any good practices I can follow to optimize database access by my python application that run in google cloud function?

From what I understand, each function may need only one connection (pool_size = 1) which needs to be maintained for a time equal to or less than that of the cloud function itself (e.g. pool_recycle = 60).

Comment: Which type of best practices? Yes you can create 1 and even more, but the best practices not always are "best practices" for all use cases so ... what is your goal? Please add more details to your question, what are you doing, what do you want to optimize? I mean, optimize the access to your database for what. Are you having any issues?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My use case is this: many independent cloud functions running on the same micro server google cloud sql mysql with small queries in writing and reading. The idea is to maximize the number of concurrent functions operating on this mysql server without breaking anything.

Comment: For now I have no problem: the RAM usage is very low and the response times are fast enough. But I have no idea how far I can go further down this road before upgrading the server or changing the logic as this type of google server only allows 250 concurrent connections.

Answer (score 2):

There is a concurrent request limit (not to be confused with concurrent connection limit) and I believe that it is 100. Additionally is a 12 concurrent connection limit per appengine instance to [CloudSQL instances](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags). For looking at slow queries I recommend enabling slow query logging on your CloudSQL instance. Instructions for setting mysql flags for CloudSQL can be found at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags).

Answer (score 2):

There are many things to consider.

Cloud Functions uses one instance per request. As well you can set a pool the recommendation is to set [1 connection at most](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas#cloud-function-limits).

Said that you also may need to consider [how much connections can handle](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas#maximum_concurrent_connections) the Cloud SQL instance you have configured for your app. For example if the queries are fast enough maybe there are no problems but just make a test to check how to limit the connections/rate of your functions.

As well check the time the some queries may have, just to consider any timeouts you could have.